# What is the best way to make a two option window?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, jlabel

Which is the best way to make a window that has a name a `JLabel` and two `JButton` components underneath.

I am new to Swing and I tried some methods but didn't understood too much from any.
What would you suggest to focus my attention on to do this specific thing?

Comment: I would recommend starting with [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to get a better grasp of the layout managers in general. But, you might be over complicating the issue and a `JOptionPane` might be a more suitable solution - see [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details. SO is not a replacement for good tutorials and trial and error

Comment: *"Also I tried making a tic tac toe game and used GridLayout(3,3) and I usually see either 3 or 2 buttons until I rescale the window or press either if them."* - Don't use `setSize` on the `JFrame`, use `pack`, it will honour the content's desired size

Comment: @MadProgrammer using pack() just make the window is as small as possible. I thought the problem was that I didn't set the size of the buttons so I went and did that but nothing changed

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I'm sorry I didn't realize you wanted me to edit question

Comment: @AlexTanasa pack honours the preferredSize of its content - without more context, that’s the best advice we can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DYM like this?

[image]

Or this?

[image]

Actually that 2nd one comes from a page linked in the first comment.

> But, you might be over complicating the issue and a `JOptionPane` might be a more suitable solution - see [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details.